# no puedo encontrar el error al intentar eliminar un nodo de un árbol binario

Tags: c++, vscode

Últimamente he estado viendo un canal de youtube sobre programación en c++. Al llegar a al tema de arboles comencé a realizar este código en vscode para crear y modificar un árbol binario, pero en la última función (la de eliminar) todo falla.

Al eliminar un nodo el código solo puede abrirse una vez más y se ve que elimina más de un nodo, a pesar de que no marca ninguna falla de error por lo que supongo que no puede ser un fallo de ";" o algo por el estilo.

Luego de varios intentos me rendí y lo traigo aquí para ver si alguien tiene alguna solución.

```
//arbol binario
    #include<iostream>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    #include<time.h>
    
    using namespace std;
    
    struct nodo{
        int n;
        nodo *izq;
        nodo *der;
        nodo *pa;
    };
    
    void menu();
    
    void injertar( nodo *&, nodo *, int );
    nodo *crear( nodo *, int );
    
    void mostrar( nodo *, int );
    bool busqueda( nodo *, int );
    
    void preorden( nodo * );
    void inorden( nodo * );
    void postorden( nodo * );
    
    void eliminar( nodo *, int );
    nodo *izquierda( nodo * );
    void reemplazar( nodo *, nodo * );
    void sierra( nodo * );
    void quemar( nodo * );
    
    int main(){
    
        menu();
    
        return 0;
    }
    void menu(){
        srand(time(NULL));
        nodo *arbol = NULL;
        int num, hojas=9, cont = 0, men, des, no;
        int a[9] = {8,3,1,6,4,7,10,14,13};
    
        do{
            cout<<endl<<"1. agregar un dato. "<<endl;
            cout<<"2. mostrar el arbol."<<endl;
            cout<<"3. buscar en el arbol."<<endl;
            cout<<"4. eliminar del arbol."<<endl;
            cout<<"5. salir."<<endl;
            cout<<"que desea elegir: ";
            cin>>men;
    
            switch( men ){
            case 1: /* cout<<"cuantos numeros desea en el arbol: ";
                    cin>>hojas; */
                    for( int i=0;i<hojas;i++ ){
                        //num = rand()% 101;
                        injertar( arbol, NULL, a[i] );
                    }
            break;
            case 2: cout<<endl<<"1. forma de arbol."<<endl;
                    cout<<"2. forma lineal (pre-orden)."<<endl;
                    cout<<"3. forma lineal (in-orden)."<<endl;
                    cout<<"4. forma lineal (post-orden)."<<endl;
                    cout<<"cual desea imprimir: ";
                    cin>>des;
                    switch( des ){
                        case 1: mostrar( arbol, cont );
                        break;
                        case 2: preorden( arbol );
                        break;
                        case 3: inorden( arbol );
                        break;
                        case 4: postorden( arbol );
                        break;
                    }
                    system( "pause" );
            break;
            case 3: cout<<"que numero desea buscar: ";
                    cin>>num;
                    
                    if( busqueda( arbol, num ) ){
                        cout<<"el numero esta en el arbol"<<endl;
                    }else{
                        cout<<"el numero NO esta en el arbol"<<endl;
                    }
                    system( "pause" );
            break;
            case 4: cout<<"que numero desea eliminar: ";
                    cin>>no;
                    eliminar( arbol, no );
                    system( "pause" );
            break;
            }
            system("cls");
        }while( men != 5 );
        
    }
    void injertar( nodo *&arbol, nodo *padre, int n ){
        
        if( arbol == NULL ){
            nodo *nuevo = crear( padre ,n );
            arbol = nuevo;
        }else{
            int sabia = arbol->n;
            if( n < sabia ){
                injertar( arbol->izq, arbol, n );
            }else{
                injertar( arbol->der, arbol, n );
            }
        }
    }
    nodo *crear( nodo *padre, int n ){
        nodo *nuevo = new nodo();
    
        nuevo->n = n;
        nuevo->der = NULL;
        nuevo->izq = NULL;
        nuevo->pa = NULL;
    
        return nuevo;
    }
    void mostrar( nodo *arbol, int c ){
        if( arbol == NULL ){
            return ;
        }else{
            mostrar( arbol->der, c+1 );
            for( int i=0;i<c;i++ ){
                cout<<"   ";
            }
            cout<<arbol->n<<endl;
            mostrar( arbol->izq, c+1);
        }
    }
    bool busqueda( nodo *arbol, int n ){
        if( arbol == NULL ){
            return false;
        }else if( arbol->n == n ){
            return true;
        }else if( n < arbol->n ){
            return busqueda( arbol->izq, n );
        }else{
            return busqueda( arbol->der, n );
        }
    }
    void preorden( nodo *arbol ){
        if( arbol == NULL ){
            return ;
        }else{
            cout<<arbol->n<<"-";
            preorden(  arbol->izq );
            preorden( arbol->der );
        }
    }
    void inorden( nodo *arbol ){
        if( arbol == NULL ){
            return ;
        }else{
            inorden( arbol->izq );
            cout<<arbol->n<<"-";
            inorden( arbol->der );
        }
    }
    void postorden( nodo *arbol ){
        if( arbol == NULL ){
            return ;
        }else{
            postorden( arbol->izq );
            postorden( arbol->der );
            cout<<arbol->n<<"-";
            
        }
    }
    
    void eliminar( nodo *arbol, int n ){
        if( arbol == NULL ){
            return ;
        }else if( n < arbol->n ){
            eliminar( arbol->izq, n );
        }else if( n > arbol->n  ){
            eliminar( arbol->der, n );
        }else{
            sierra( arbol );
        }
    }
    nodo *izquierda( nodo *arbol ){
        if( arbol == NULL ){
            return NULL;
        }
        if( arbol->izq ){
            return izquierda( arbol->izq );
        }else{
            return arbol; 
        }
    }
    void reemplazar( nodo *arbol, nodo *nuevo ){
        if( arbol->pa != NULL ){
            if( arbol->n == arbol->pa->izq->n ){
                arbol->pa->izq = nuevo;
            }else if( arbol->n == arbol->pa->der->n ){
                arbol->pa->der = nuevo;
            }
        }
        if( nuevo != NULL ){
            nuevo->pa = arbol->pa;
        }
    }
    void quemar( nodo *hierba ){
        hierba->izq = NULL;
        hierba->der = NULL;
    
        delete hierba;
    }
    void sierra( nodo *hierba ){
        if( (hierba->izq != NULL ) && (hierba->der != NULL) ){
            nodo *izq = izquierda( hierba->der );
            hierba->n = izq->n;
            sierra( izq );
        }else if( hierba->izq != NULL ){
            reemplazar( hierba, hierba->izq );
            quemar( hierba );
        }else if( hierba->der != NULL ){
            reemplazar( hierba, hierba->der );
            quemar( hierba );
        }else{
            reemplazar( hierba, NULL );
            quemar( hierba );
        }   
    }
```

Comment: Son 200 líneas de código, no podemos buscar tu problema ahí. Por favor, reduce tu ejemplo. También sería muy útil que proporcionaras un ejemplo de los datos que estás entrando, los datos que esperas obtener y los datos que estás obteniendo.